# Expanding on a *, using glob

Tags: c, shell, glob

I'm trying to expand *, so I've done some research and it seems that glob is the function to use. Just like linux when you type ls *.c, it will return you all the files that contains .c

I've got myself to start so I know that I need to malloc glob_t first, so here it is:

```
glob_t *globbuf = (glob_t*)malloc(sizeof(glob_t));
```

After this, I'm not sure how to work this out... going through internet has shown me some examples, but I don't get quite how it works. This is what I figured out:

```
if(glob("*.c",GLOB_DOOFFS,NULL,globbuf)) {
   // what am i supposed to write in here?}

globbuf->gl_pathv[0] = "ls";
```

Comment: What part of [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple, straight-forward example that Works As Expected:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(char const * epath, int eerrno) { return 0; }

int main()
{
    glob_t globbuf = {0};

    glob("*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS, foo, &globbuf);

    for (size_t i = 0; i != globbuf.gl_pathc; ++i)
    {
        printf("Found: %s\n", globbuf.gl_pathv[i]);
    }

    globfree(&globbuf);
}
```